# Extend common CSS definition in React

Tags: css, reactjs, stylesheet

I am writing a simple React component where I change the component style when the mouse pointer is on the component. I was able to make my component work but I have two stylesheets that are almost similar. One style is used for `onMouseOver` and the other is used for `onMouseOut` event. The difference between the two stylesheets is only one line: the `border` definition.

I would like to avoid duplicated CSS definitions and I would like to simplify my CSS according to the following:

- one basic stylesheet which describes the looking of the component
- one style extends basic for onMouseOver event (contains only border)
- another style extend basic for onMouseOut event (contains only border)

This is the stylesheet definition that I would like to use:

```
const STYLE = {
  box: {
     '-moz-border-radius': '15px',
     '-moz-box-shadow': '#B3B3B3 13px 13px 13px',
     '-webkit-box-shadow': '#B3B3B3 13px 13px 13px',
     'background-color': '#E3A20B',
     'border-radius': '15px',
     'border': '5px solid #FFFF00',
     'box-shadow': '#B3B3B3 13px 13px 13px',
     'float': 'left',
     'height': '215px',
     'margin': '15px',
     'width': '150px'
  },

  boxMouseOver: {
    'border': '5px solid #000000',
  },

  boxMouseOut: {
    'border': '5px solid #FFFF00',
  }
}
```

This is my working code uses two stylesheets:

```
<div style={this.state.mouseOver ? STYLE.boxOver : STYLE.boxDefault} onMouseOver={...} onMouseOut={...}>
    ...
</div>
```

And this is what I would like to do, but unfortunately it does not work:

```
<div style={STYLE.box, this.state.mouseOver ? STYLE.boxMouseOver : STYLE.boxMouseOut} onMouseOver={...} onMouseOut={...}>
    ...
</div>
```

What is the proper way to add two different styles to a component OR how I can extend the STYLE.box constant and redefine the border property in descent stylesheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
const STYLE = {
  box: {
    '-moz-border-radius': '15px',
    '-moz-box-shadow': '#B3B3B3 13px 13px 13px',
    '-webkit-box-shadow': '#B3B3B3 13px 13px 13px',
    'background-color': '#E3A20B',
    'border-radius': '15px',
    'border': '5px solid #FFFF00',
    'box-shadow': '#B3B3B3 13px 13px 13px',
    'float': 'left',
    'height': '215px',
    'margin': '15px',
    'width': '150px'
  },

  boxMouseOver: {
    'border': '5px solid #000000',
  },

  boxMouseOut: {
    'border': '5px solid #FFFF00',
  }
}

<div style={{...STYLE.BOX, ...(this.state.mouseOver ? STYLE.boxOver : STYLE.boxDefault)}} onMouseOver={...} onMouseOut={...}>
    ...
</div>
```

This must work

Comment: That is so tricky syntax especially if I compare it with Java ;) Anyway, It work like a charm. Could you please add the missing '}' char in your example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use object destruct pattern to hold the common parts of you styles and change whatever property you need in that object as needed.

```
const commonStyle = {
  box: {
    '-moz-border-radius': '15px',
    '-moz-box-shadow': '#B3B3B3 13px 13px 13px',
    '-webkit-box-shadow': '#B3B3B3 13px 13px 13px',
    'background-color': '#E3A20B',
    'border-radius': '15px',
    'border': '5px solid #FFFF00',
    'box-shadow': '#B3B3B3 13px 13px 13px',
    'float': 'left',
    'height': '215px',
    'margin': '15px',
    'width': '150px'
  }
}

const boxMouseOverStyles = {...commonStyle, ...{'border': '5px solid #000000'}};
const boxMouseOutStyles = {...commonStyle, ...{'border': '5px solid #FFFF00'}};

<div style={this.state.mouseOver ? boxMouseOverStyles : boxMouseOutStyles} onMouseOver={...} onMouseOut={...}>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it seems that the "...commonStyle" part is not working. The boxMouseOverStyles and boxMouseOutStyles only contain the border definition. The rest is missing.